# various clients cannot RDP to AWS Windows Server 2016

Tags: aws, rdp

I am trying to RDP connect to a AWS windows machine from ubuntu 16.04.

I tried Vinagre (3.18.2) and Remmina (1.1.2) unsuccessfully.
I **succeeded connecting to the machine from a mac and a windows machines** on the same network the ubuntu is on, so the remote machine is okay and there is no network issue.

The target machine is Windows Server 2016.
I do not have a `~/.freerdp/known_hosts` file.

Running Remmina from the commandline, I see

```
connected to ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3389
recv: Connection reset by peer
```

> Allow connections only from computers running Remote Desktop with NLA" is deselected on the target machine.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [Secure RDS (Remote Desktop Services) Connections with SSL](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff458357.aspx):

1. Open the group policy settings and go to
   `Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host\Security`.
2. Enable the security layer and select RDP.